# How to get a page's Google Analytics tracking ID via a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I used to use `window.ga.getAll()[1].b.data.values[':trackingId'];` a few months ago and it works well. But recently it's not working and says `getAll is not a function`.

What should I do instead?

update:

- I am using this for a page created by me, not a 3rd-party page.
- I am sure the ga is loaded when I make this call.

Comment: What page are you using this on? Are you sure the GA is loaded when your script runs?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and I have just updated my question.

Comment: But why I can't even use `ga.getAll` in my console? I am sure `ga` is loaded because `ga` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAll` is not immediately available when google analytics loads:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ga-object-methods-reference

> Don't — use ga object methods outside a readyCallback as the methods
>   may not be available yet.

Instead, try this:

```
window.ga(() => window.ga.getAll()[1].b.data.values[':trackingId']);
```

which will run your function as part of a readyCallback.